# Powershell script extract AD group members - find last-login time for each user

Tags: powershell, active-directory, quest

I'm trying to create a script that will pull a list of group members from AD and run a foreach loop to determine when the last time each user logged into any given domain controller. I got some of the code for the measure-latest function [here](https://dmitrysotnikov.wordpress.com/2008/07/16/measure-latest-finding-the-latest-date-time/) . I would like to have the script run through the foreach loop and print the samAccountName (username) and last login time stamp (measure-latest) for each user in the group, but so far have not been able to get it working. I think I've got something wrong in logic but i can't seem to figure it out. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

```
# Get a list of last login times for a group of users
# Script Requires Quest Cmdlet features: https://support.software.dell.com/activeroles-server/download-new-releases
Add-PSSnapin Quest.ActiveRoles.ADManagement

# filter out $nulls and produce the latest of them
function Measure-Latest {
    BEGIN { $latest = $null }
    PROCESS {
            if (($_ -ne $null) -and (($latest -eq $null) -or ($_ -gt $latest))) {
                $latest = $_ 
            }
    }
    END { $latest }
}

# Get list of group users by username
Get-ADGroupMember -identity "Domain Admins" | select samAccountName | Export-csv -path C:\Scripts\UserInformationByGroup\Groupmembers.csv -NoTypeInformation

# Get list of users from group, assign user value
$userlist = import-csv C:\Scripts\UserInformationByGroup\Groupmembers.csv
$user = $userlist | Select samAccountName

# Loop through list of users and print Username ------ Last Login time 
foreach ($user in $userlist) {
Get-QADComputer -ComputerRole DomainController | foreach {
(Get-QADUser -Service $_.Name -SamAccountName $user).LastLogon
} | Measure-Latest $samAccountName | out-file -filepath C:\Scripts\UserInformationByGroup\userListLastLogin.txt -append
}
```

I should mention that when I run the script like this, and just enter each username manually it works and prints the last login time:

```
Add-PSSnapin Quest.ActiveRoles.ADManagement

function Measure-Latest {
    BEGIN { $latest = $null }
    PROCESS {
            if (($_ -ne $null) -and (($latest -eq $null) -or ($_ -gt $latest))) {
                $latest = $_ 
            }
    }
    END { $latest }
}
Get-QADComputer -ComputerRole DomainController | foreach {
(Get-QADUser -Service $_.Name -SamAccountName USER_NAME_HERE).LastLogon
} | Measure-Latest
```

Answer (score 0):

This part of the pipeline makes no sense:

```
| Measure-Latest $samAccountName |
```

Since nothing is assigned to the variable `$samAccountName`

You'll need to add [pipeline support](http://learn-powershell.net/2013/05/07/tips-on-implementing-pipeline-support/) to your `Measure-Latest` function, like so:

```
function Measure-Latest {
  [CmdletBinding]
  param(
    [parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$True,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True)]
    $LastLogon
  )

  # rest of the script (begin-process-end blocks) goes here
}
```

And now you can pipe the `LastLogon` values directly to the function:

```
(Get-QADUser -SamAccountName $user).LastLogon |Measure-Latest | Out-File #or whatever
```

Thanks to the `ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName` flag, you can now also pipe the entire object to the function:

```
Get-QADUser -SamAccountName $user | Measure-Latest
```

Because the parameter name (`$LastLogon`) matches that property anyways

---

In addition to that, I would probably change the logic a bit, so that you don't perform 1 LDAP query per DC per user. If you have 5 Domain Controllers and 200 users, that's now 1000 individual queries to the directory service.

You could simply retrieve ALL the users from each DC, in a single query, using the `-LdapFilter` parameter with `Get-QADUser`:

```
$LDAPClauses = @()

foreach($user in $userlist){
  $LDAPClauses += "(samaccountname={0})" -f $user
}

# The | in an LDAP filter means logical OR
$LDAPFilter = "(&(LastLogon=*)(|$(-join($LDAPClauses))))"
```

Now you can run just a single query per DC:

```
Get-QADUser -LdapFilter $LDAPFilter
```

and it'll retrieve all the users in $userlist that has a `LastLogon` attribute value on that specific DC (you're not really interested in `$null`-values anyways, right?)

Comment: Thank you Mathias, i will try this out today and report back after testing. I thought the nested for-each was a bad way to do it with all the separate queries but I couldn't think of anything else. Will report back results soon, thanks again. Also wanted to mention, the $samAccountName variable was a typo, should have been '| Measure-Latest $user', as I was trying to have the user account name printed after the LastLogon time.